# Symmetry of bosonic propagators and vertices under the exchange of indices

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, propagator, bosons

Quoting P. Cvitanovic's lecture notes on field theory:

> Assumption of additivity of probability amplitudes then implies that the bosonic propagators and vertices must be symmetric under the interchange of indices.

Image of the relevant part:

[image]

I couldn't understand how the assumption of additivity implies this particular symmetry of the propagators and vertices under the exchange of indices?

Comment: Can you add a link to the lecture notes and reference to page so that it is easily searchable? Also it would be nice if you add a couple of relevant equations in your question

Comment: @st.vit I added a link to the relevant chapter of the lecture notes.

Comment: So I have to look through a whole chapter of a non scannable document? If you're looking for answers try to be as helpful as possible to the potential responder

Comment: @st.vit I have added a screenshot of the document from the part of interest. If you wish, you can check it out.

Comment: "this argument is similar to the one we shall use for fermions in chapter 4", the scan says. What does Ch. 4 say?